# Is it safe to run docker container in production as root?

Tags: docker

How safe it is to run docker container as root user in production environment ? Is this standard practice or it is recommended to run docker container as non root user ?

Edit :

My question assumes running docker daemon, docker client and application inside docker as root ( everything as root docker server, client and application inside container )

Comment: This isn't clear enough. There is a user inside the Docker container, a user executing the `docker` client command, and a user running the `docker` server. Which of these three users is root?

Answer (score 3):

It is safer, and better practice, to run as non-root, both in docker and non-docker environments. However, running as root within a docker container is at least somewhat less dangerous than running as root directly in the primary OS, but definitely for a production system running as root is pretty much unheard of by any company with even the most basic security concerns.

Comment: Thanks Peter, If i run docker container as root user can i do any harm to the physical host ?